# Problemas al usar kartik-mpdf en yii2

Tags: yii2, mpdf

Estoy usando el mPdf de Kartik en yii2, pero no me funciona bien, ya que al mostrar el pdf por primera vez me muestra caracteres raros como estos:

> %PDF-1.4 %���� 3 0 obj <> /Contents 4 0 R>> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream
>   x��[�r��3�U�$U4���-�*���"ѹ�r�D��K+Z�d��y\~70�р���R�E���o���A��I����'cُG_��_&Ǒ�d����ϧ�����n�"��e���ѿ��Fv��cGo��ge�׋�#-�3#3��wͤ�\9�n
>   ɍ���{���>ci-�Z%k�g.���ZK������gi��Q섙�f^�� ӖOv�

Si actualizo la página entonces me sale bien el PDF

¿Cuál será el problema?

¿Cómo hacer para que me salga bien desde la primera vez?

Este es el codigo que utilizo:

```
public function actionImprimepdf() {         
    $periodo = Periodoactivo::find()->one();
    $empresa = Empresa::find()->one();
    $modelo = VFacturacion::find()->where('Mes = :mes and Anno = :anno',[':mes' => $periodo->Mes, ':anno' => $periodo->Anno])->all();

    $content = $this->renderPartial('imprimepdf', ['modelo' => $modelo, 'empresa' => $empresa,]);

    $pdf = new Pdf([
        'mode' => Pdf::MODE_UTF8,
        'destination' => Pdf::DEST_DOWNLOAD,
        'filename' => 'pdf/Facturas.pdf',
        'content' => $content,
        'cssFile' => 'css/printfactura.css',
        'options' => ['title' => 'Facturas'],
        'methods' => [
           // 'SetHeader'=>['Krajee Report Header'],
           // 'SetFooter'=>['{PAGENO}'],
        ]
    ]);
    // return the pdf output as per the destination setting
    Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_RAW;
    Yii::$app->response->headers->add('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');

    return $pdf->render();
}
```

Comment: Parece que estableces la codificación después de la salida del PDF. Prueba a establecer la codificación (quizá `utf-8`)  al principio.

Comment: Edite la pregunta publicando el codigo que uso

Comment: Prueba poniendo el mode así: **`'mode' => Pdf::MODE_BLANK,`**

Comment: Probe cambiando el parametro 'mode' con todas las opciones, y sigue el problema. Ahora veo que este problema me lo da con un documento de hasta 77 paginas, si supera esta cantidad de paginas me muestra directamente el pdf pero con 0 paginas. El documento tiene 256 paginas pero puede llagar hasta 300 o 350. Existe algun limite para la generacion de paginas con mPdf ?

Answer (score 0):

Pues el problema parece que estaba en el uso de ajax.

Deshabilite pajax del datagrid y ya funciona bien como debe ser.

```
'pjax' => false
```